# Count number of Blackjack's that occur in 100 2-card deals

Tags: python, blackjack, playing-cards

I need to count the number of times Blackjack occurs in 100 2-card deals from a 5 deck shoe. So far I have this:

## str() - convert to string

```
def str(draw):
    suits = {
        'S':'Spades',
        'H':'Hearts',
        'D':'Diamonds',
        'C':'Clubs'
        }
    cards = [
        'Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5',
        '6', '7', '8', '9', '10',
        'Jack', 'Queen', 'King'
        ]
    # create the human-readable string for the given card
    str = '{} of {}'.format(cards[draw[0]], suits[draw[1]])
    return str
```

## convert() - converts an integer (0-259; i.e, 5 decks) to a card

```
#             Return list with card (0-12) and suit (S, H, D, C)
def convert(x):
    if x >= 0 and x <= 51:
        card = x%13
        suit = 'SHDC'[x/13]
        return card, suit, str([card,suit])
    elif x >= 52 and x <= 103:
        x = x - 52
        card = x%13
        suit = 'SHDC'[x/13]
        return card, suit, str([card,suit])
    elif x >= 104 and x <= 155:
        x = x - 104
        card = x%13
        suit = 'SHDC'[x/13]
        return card, suit, str([card,suit])
    elif x >= 156 and x <= 207:
        x = x - 156
        card = x%13
        suit = 'SHDC'[x/13]
        return card, suit, str([card,suit])
    elif x >= 208 and x <= 259:
        x = x - 208
        card = x%13
        suit = 'SHDC'[x/13]
        return card, suit, str([card,suit])
```

## draw_n() - draws n cards without replacement from a deck

```
def draw_n(n):
    from random import sample
    cards = []
    # Make sure a valid number is entered
     if n >0 and n <= 260:
        # Sample without replacement
        for x in sample(xrange(0,260),n):
            # Append converted card to list 'cards'
            cards.append(convert(x))
    return cards
```

## score1(hand) - Compute the score of first card in 2-card hand

```
def score1(hand):
    if hand[0][0] == 0:
        val1 = 11
        return val1
    elif hand[0][0] == 1:
        val1 = 2
        return val1
    elif hand[0][0] == 2:
        val1 = 3
    return val1
elif hand[0][0] == 3:
    val1 = 4
    return val1
elif hand[0][0] == 4:
    val1 = 5
    return val1
elif hand[0][0] == 5:
    val1 = 6
    return val1
elif hand[0][0] == 6:
    val1 = 7
    return val1
elif hand[0][0] == 7:
    val1 = 8
    return val1
elif hand[0][0] == 8:
    val1 = 9
    return val1
elif hand[0][0] == 9 or hand[0][0] == 10 or hand[0][0] == 11 or hand[0][0] == 12:
    val1 = 10
    return val1
```

## score2(hand) - Compute the score of second card in 2-card hand

```
def score2(hand):
    if hand[1][0] == 0:
        val2 = 11
        return val2
    elif hand[1][0] == 1:
        val2 = 2
        return val2
    elif hand[1][0] == 2:
        val2 = 3
        return val2
    elif hand[1][0] == 3:
        val2 = 4
        return val2
    elif hand[1][0] == 4:
        val2 = 5
        return val2
    elif hand[1][0] == 5:
        val2 = 6
        return val2
    elif hand[1][0] == 6:
        val2 = 7
        return val2
    elif hand[1][0] == 7:
        val2 = 8
        return val2
    elif hand[1][0] == 8:
        val2 = 9
        return val2
    elif hand[1][0] == 9 or hand[1][0] == 10 or hand[1][0] == 11 or hand[1][0] == 12:
        val2 = 10
        return val2
```

I want to be able to draw 10 hands with:

```
hands = [draw_n(2) for i in range(100)]
```

After this, what would be the most efficient way to count the number of time blackjack occurs?

Comment: Maybe you could have `draw_n` return 0 if there is not a blackjack and 1 if there is.  Then just add them up.

Answer (score 0):

```
hand_total = [sum(x) for x in hands]
hand_total.count(21)
```